# how to make these navigation items stay close to each other with minimum space using flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Works</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
```

Hello, guys, I am trying to have a navigation with flexbox but there is way too much space between the flex items

```
<ul><li><a href="#">Blog</a></li> </ul>


.nav ul {
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
    align-content: flex-start;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
   }
    .nav ul li {
        flex: 1;
    }
```

Comment: You can accept the answer by clicking on the check mark.

Comment: @samcorcos The OP hasn't been around after you answered, so give users reasonable time to evaluate given answers before asking them to accept

Comment: @LGSon Sorry, there was a previous answer that appears to have been removed in which @pedroyanky commented that the `flex: 1` answer (my answer) was the correct answer, and @pedroyanky upvoted my answer instead of accepting it as correct. I think he is just a new user and does not know the protocol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is `flex: 1`, which tells each individual `li` to fill all remaining space. This (in your case) effectively breaks the `flex-start` you define in `ul`.

You need to change your CSS to the following:

```
ul {
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}
ul li {
  padding-left: 10px; /* or some other padding */
  padding-right: 10px;
}
```

Check out this example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vWEPNe